# Drupal Domain Access Authentication

Tags: authentication, drupal-6, drupal-domain-access

I am using the domain access module https://drupal.org/project/domain for a city site. They have a lot of sub domains and these work fine for authentication. The users can go to any subdomain fire.#####city.gov/user and are able to login fine.

Now we are using the same access module to share content for another domain entirely ######lovecity.com. You can visit the login page ######lovecity.com/user and try to login. When you do it gives you an access denied. From what we can see the auth token only works for #####city.gov. Any help getting the authentication to work for both domains would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research I came across this in the readme text:

> 1.4.1   Logging In To Multiple Domains
>
> ```
> The Domain Access module allows the creation of domains with different
> hosts.  However, security standards dictate that cookies can only be
> read from the issuing domain.
>
> As a result, you may configure your site as follows, but when you do so,
> users cannot be logged through a single sign in.
>
>   example.com
>   one.example.com
>   myexample.com
>   thisexample.com
>
> While example.com and one.example.com can share a login cookie, the
> other two domains cannot read that cookie.  This is an internet standard,
> not a bug.
>
> Note: See the INSTALL.txt for instructions regarding Drupal's default
> cookie handling.
> ```

This is no a bug like I thought. I am answering it here so that others may learn from the time I spent trying to solve it.